# NullpointerException on SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, simplecursoradapter, custom-cursor

My main page is an ViewPager with 6 pages (first one settings, other 5 are listview and use this cursoradapter for data)

In settings there is one button which opens another activity, users change some settings there and then that activity will end with finish() (or super.onBackpressed()) but everytime I call finish() an NullPointerException comes up

What am I doing wrong?

This is my CursorAdapter

```
package com.whd.roosters.adapters;

import com.whd.roosters.R;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Build;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RoosterCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    private Cursor cursor;
    private Context context;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") //New constructor available from API 11
    public RoosterCursorAdapter(Context mContext, int layout, Cursor mCursor, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(mContext, layout, mCursor, from, to);
        cursor = mCursor;
        context = mContext;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public RoosterCursorAdapter(Context mContext, int layout, Cursor mCursor, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
        super(mContext, layout, mCursor, from, to, flags);
        cursor = mCursor;
        context = mContext;
    }

    public int getImage(int uur) {
        if (uur == 1) return R.drawable.eerste;
        if (uur == 2) return R.drawable.tweede;
        if (uur == 3) return R.drawable.derde;
        if (uur == 4) return R.drawable.vierde;
        if (uur == 5) return R.drawable.vijfde;
        if (uur == 6) return R.drawable.zesde;
        if (uur == 7) return R.drawable.zevende;
        if (uur == 8) return R.drawable.achtste;
        return 1;
    }

    public View getView(int pos, View row, ViewGroup root) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(pos);

        String uur = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("uur"));
        String les = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("les"));
        String lok = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("lok"));
        String doc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("doc"));

        ImageView UUR = null;
        TextView  LES = null;
        TextView  LOK = null;
        TextView  DOC = null;

        if (lok.contains("Vrij")) {
            if (row == null) row = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_rooster_vrij, null);
            UUR = ( ImageView ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_VRIJ_IMAGEVIEW_UUR );
            LOK = ( TextView  ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_VRIJ_TEXTVIEW_VRIJ );
        } else {
            if (row == null) row = ((LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService("layout_inflater")).inflate(R.layout.listview_item_rooster, null);
            UUR = ( ImageView ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_IMAGEVIEW_UUR   );
            LES = ( TextView  ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_TEXTVIEW_LES    );
            LOK = ( TextView  ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_TEXTVIEW_LOKAAL );
            DOC = ( TextView  ) row.findViewById( R.id.LISTVIEW_ITEM_ROOSTER_TEXTVIEW_DOCENT );
        }

        UUR.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        if ((context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 10) > 10) {
            UUR.setMaxHeight(context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels / 10);
        } else {
            UUR.setMaxHeight(100);
        }
        UUR.setMinimumHeight(50);
        UUR.setImageResource(getImage(Integer.parseInt(uur)));

        LOK.setText(lok);
        if (LES != null) LES.setText("Les: " + les);
        if (DOC != null) DOC.setText("Docent: " + doc);

        return row;
    }
}
```

This is the stacktrace

```
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562): java.lang.NullPointerException
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at com.whd.roosters.adapters.RoosterCursorAdapter.getView(RoosterCursorAdapter.java:72)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1597)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:695)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:666)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4215)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.widget.AbsListView$TwFlingRunnable.run(AbsListView.java:3431)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:912)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:670)
04-07 16:08:39.430: E/AndroidRuntime(4562):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: your problem is on line 72, start there.

Comment: yes I know, it is this line UUR.setAdjustViewBounds(true); so the ImageView UUR is null, but how could that happen after inflating a new layout when the row is null or getting an reference to it when row already exist?

Comment: then you probably have a problem with the id of this view.

Comment: When opening the activity first time it works, only after opening and finishing the other activity started from the settings screen, this exception shows

Comment: my guess would be that you have some problem with your "if" statement, and while you think you got the right layout, I guess you are getting the other one.

Comment: I think you're right, but how? When the second activity ends an SQLite DB is updated with an asynctask, in the onPostExecute method, notifyDataSetChanged is called, and this adapter is called again

Comment: I still don't know how this could happen, but you're right. If you create an answer for this I will accept it;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is on line 72:

```
UUR.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
```

my guess would be that you have some problem with your "if" statement, and while you think you got the right layout, I guess you are getting the other one.